# Protoc: How to generate multiple Java source files?

Tags: java, protocol-buffers

After compiling a large Protobuf definition I am getting a 6 MB Java source code file.

Because of its size working with that file is a big pain as I develop in Eclipse and Eclipse totally stalls/crashes whenever I open that file.

Is there a way to let protoc generate multiple Java source code files instead of one big file?

Answer (score 47, accepted):

Actually, there is. It's not documented, but you can add a line to your `.proto` file like this:

```
option java_multiple_files = true;
```

This will put each top-level message type from the `.proto` file into an independent `.java` file. Note that you'll of course have to update all your code to import these classes from their new locations. Note also that `protoc` will still generate the "outer" class it did before, just without the inner classes nested within it. The outer class is still the place to go to get the file's descriptor, top-level extensions, and other non-class things.

All that said, if you have a `.proto` file that big, I strongly recommend splitting up the `.proto` file itself into smaller files that import each other.